# necklace of numbers with bounded distance

Tags: combinatorics

Starting from the numbers `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12` arrange them in a circle so the difference `|x-y|` between  neighbors is **1** or **2**.

If we are working mod 12 so that `12 = 0`, how many possible arrangements are there?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I can help put this problem in context. I wrote a Perl program to compute the number of these arrangements for $n\ge 2$ and not just $n=12.$ This gave the following sequence.

$$1, 2, 6, 24, 32, 46, 58, 82, 112, 158, 220, 316, 450, 650, 938, 1364, 1982, 2892, 4220, 6170, 9022,\ldots$$

I then checked the OEIS and found this [OEIS link](http://oeis.org/A137725). Apparently this problem reduces to an enumeration of hamiltonian circuits in certain circulant graphs by an obvious bijection. The OEIS entry contains a link to a paper where your problem is solved, so perhaps you can start by studying that. Considering the bibliography of the linked paper it looks like there is quite a bit of relevant literature on this subject.

This was the Perl program:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

sub checkdiff {
    my ($n, $a, $b) = @_;

    my $d = $a-$b;
    $d += $n if $d<0;

    return 1 if $d==1 || $d==2 || $d==$n-2 || $d==$n-1;
    return 0;
}

sub compute {
    my ($n, $seq, $rest, $count) = @_;

    if(!scalar(@$rest)){
      if(checkdiff($n, $seq->[0], $seq->[-1])){
          # print join(', ', @$seq);
          # print "\n";
          $$count++;
      }

      return;
    }

    for(my $pos = 0; $pos<scalar(@$rest); $pos++){
      my $el = $rest->[$pos];

      if(checkdiff($n, $seq->[-1], $el)){
          push @$seq, $el;
          splice @$rest, $pos, 1;

          compute($n, $seq, $rest, $count);

          splice @$rest, $pos, 0, $el;
          pop @$seq;
      }
    }

}


MAIN: {
    my $mx = shift || 5;

    die "MAX at least two please" if $mx<2;

    for(my $n=2; $n<=$mx; $n++){
      my $count = 0;

      compute($n, [0], [1..($n-1)], \$count);
      print (($n==2 ? "" : ", ") . $count);
    }
    print "\n";

    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 you should mention that it doesn't agree in the first few values.

Comment: Thank you. This disagreement is mentioned in the description near the top.